# QMYSQL driver not loaded (Openserver)

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm trying to add my database to a QT-project. However, it gives the error "QMYSQL driver not loaded". I use openserver to work with mysql.

1. I created an instance of QSqlDatabase.
2. I entered host name, database name, port, user name and password.
3. I add sql to .pro file.
4. I added bin and lib of MySql to path.

> !
> [image: mainwindow.cpp]
> [image: .pro file]
> [image: mysql screen]
> [image: .path]

Comment: As you can see there is no Qt mysql plugin available (thx to the MySQL licensing stuff) - you have to compile it by your own. There are plenty of threads about this here and the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers) also states how to do so

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any experience with compiling, take a look here:

https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases

you must then copy the files into your qt/mingw/bin folder.
the versions must match